# How to generate type3 message for NTLM Authentication?

Tags: ntlm, mail-server

I want to send a test mail from linux server. 
after telnet and ehlo I use AUTH NTLM, then I send the type1 message, I get a response, but I do not know how to form the type 3 message in order to successfully authenticate. Do I need to use some information from type 2 message?
here is one example 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-smtpntlm/a048c79f-7597-401b-bcb4-521d682de765

I need to understand what is done in 6 & 7 steps.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the type 2 message, you will need the `NTLM CHALLENGE_MESSAGE`. I implemented this in Javascript, so you can have a look at my implementation for the exact protocol: https://github.com/SamDecrock/node-http-ntlm/blob/master/ntlm.js